# How do I create a new input on tab with jQuery (or vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like many things, my question is best explained with a picture:
http://gyazo.com/f7df971c91a5ab4a4969d12f4c5f32b6.png?1329575807

When the user is on the last field in each column, I want a new input to pop up underneath the current input when they press tab (similar to what Quizlet does).

I don't have that much experience with jQuery, could someone help me out, or point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
So here's what I have currently:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('section#attendance input:last').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 9)
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var num = parseInt($this.attr('name').match(/\d+(,\d+)?/)[0]) + 1;
        $this.parent().append('<input type="text" name="attendance[' + num +']" value="Name and Position" class="medium" />');
    }
});
```

});

For some reason, after it creates the first new input, it doesn't use that new input for the tab trigger, but rather the input it used before. Any idea why?

Comment: Regarding your edit: that would be because you attach event handlers (i.e. `keydown`) to the element you remove, but not to the one you add. See the use of `live` in the answers below to fix that issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type="text"]:last').live('keyup',
    function(e) {
        if (e.which == 9) {
            $(this).parent().append($('<input/>', {
                value: '',
                type: 'text',
                            name: 'YOUR_CHOICE',
                            class: 'YOUR_CHOICE'
            }));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the selector, but for some reason it doesn't detect the new last element when I create the new input. I've edited my original post, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the column fields in some contanier (e.g. a 'column' div) and the fields have class `field`, and the last field has class `last`, then this might help:

```
$('.last').live('focusout', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.removeClass('last');
  $this.parent().append('<input class="field last" type="text"></input>');
});
```

Of course, you could append something a lot prettier than that ;)

Comment: Thanks! I've slightly modified this to (kinda) get it working. However, for some reason it doesn't use the new input that was created as the new 'last' element, but rather the original last element. Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: @user1045696 - I reckon that would be due to the 'last' class manipulation. Can you see that it is removed from the input it was on initially, and added to the new one, by inspecting the inputs in the browser?

Comment: Also, use of `live` here is important. It lets jquery handle the focusout event on new elements without you having to explicitly create new event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function KeyDown(e) {
    if (e.which == 9) { // tab
        // Do your stuff
    }
}

$(document).keydown(KeyDown);
```

In your case you'll probably not want to bind to document, but to the last element. Or you could do that focus check inside the handler method.

Comment: Detecting the ket is part 1 of the question. Where's the input creation part?